# Custom function making troubles in get_permalink for ACF relationship fields

Tags: permalinks, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a custom function to add .html to my custom posts & pages, working with WPML.

This script is creating a bug on [ACF relationship field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/) permalink.

My custom function :

```
function custom_post_permalink ($post_link) {
    global $post;
    if($post) {
        $type = get_post_type($post->ID);
        $post_type_data = get_post_type_object( $type );
        $post_type_slug = $post_type_data->rewrite['slug'];
        $post_type_slug_translated = apply_filters( 'wpml_get_translated_slug', $post_type_slug, $type);
        $translated_home_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_home_url', home_url());
        $be_current_lang = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );
        if($be_current_lang=='fr'){
            return $translated_home_url . $post_type_slug_translated . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html';
        } else {    
        return $translated_home_url .'/'. $post_type_slug_translated . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html';
        }
    }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink');
```

So when i query my posts/pages/customs posts and i want to display the relationship pages, every data display well.

EXCEPT

```
get_the_permalink( $event_city->ID )
```

that display the curent page link, or the link of the item in the loop. Not the one of relationship. ( so you have good title link, and wrong url )

nb : if i output `$event_city->ID` i have the ID of the relationship field, and as i say, it works well with `get_the_title( $event_city->ID )`

nb2 : i have try with `get_permalink`, `get_post_permalink`, and `get_the_permalink`, same result.

if i deactivate my function, everything works well.

But i can not figure what make this trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the global `$post` variable for filters like this.

In your example you're passing `$event_city->ID` to `get_the_permalink()`. This implies that the `$event_city` post is not for the same post as the current `$post` object. This is normal. Sometimes you want to use a function like `get_the_title()` or `get_the_permalink()` without changing the global `$post` variable.

At some stage the value of `get_the_permalink()` is passed through the `post_type_link` filter. The problem then is that your `custom_post_permalink()` function *completely disregards the specific post that the link was requested for* (`$event_city`), and instead only uses the global post variable. This means that when the `get_the_permalink()` function is called outside the loop, it will only ever retrieve a link based on the current post in the loop.

So how do we use the correct post in the filter? [As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/), `post_type_link` filter callbacks receive a post object as the 2nd argument. This object will represent the post that the link was requested for in `get_the_permalink()`. So you need to use that object in your function:

```
function custom_post_permalink( $post_link, $post ) { // Accept $post argument.
    $post_type                 = get_post_type( $post->ID ); // $post now refers to the one passed as an argument.
    $post_type_data            = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
    $post_type_slug            = $post_type_data->rewrite['slug'];
    $post_type_slug_translated = apply_filters( 'wpml_get_translated_slug', $post_type_slug, $post_type );
    $translated_home_url       = apply_filters( 'wpml_home_url', home_url() );
    $be_current_lang           = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );

    if ( $be_current_lang === 'fr' ) {
        return $translated_home_url . $post_type_slug_translated . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html';
    } else {
        return $translated_home_url . '/' . $post_type_slug_translated . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html';
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink', 10, 2 ); // Specify that we're accepting 2 arguments.
```

Whenever possible you should not rely on the global `$post` variable. If the filter or action hook passed a post object to the callback function, always use that. If you had filtered `the_title` the same way, relying on global `$post`, you'd be having the exact same issue (in that case the filter gets the post *ID*, which you can use to get the object).

Comment: You're a GENIUS ! explained like this, it seems so logic... Thank you very much.